# Unable to access URL with Name but works with IP address

Tags: react-native, fetch

I am using following fetch command and it is working fine.

The problem is: This is working only with IP and not with Name. 
If I try to replace IP and put **actual name** something like this then it is throiwng error
Can you please tell what is the problem , Or can you refer something , I will read about that.

Not working with Name :
"http://**tmSpn01.LayaMs.com:5432**/Quotations/api/UserQuotations"

Working with IP address:

```
 fetch('http://192.78.87.89:3472/Quotations/api/UserQuotations')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      return responseJson.articles;
    })
    .then( articles  => {
      setArticles(articles);
      //console.log(articles);
      setLoading(false);
    })
    .catch( error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
```

Comment: Check your `UserQuotations` file on the server, that it is locating on this path `http://tmSpn01.LayaMs.com:5432/Quotations/api/UserQuotations` or not

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying. In Post man  it is working with IP address and Name also.  I went to that File which you mentioned. It is WebApi Which I developed in C sharp. It looks like following. There is nothing to mention about the Name to IP address.
        `[HttpPost]
        [Route("api/UserQuotations")]
        public IHttpActionResult UserQuotations(Parameter paramObj)
        {
            string response = "";
            List<object> quotationList = new List<object>();
            QuotationClient client = InitializeService(paramObj.user, paramObj.password, paramObj.EndpointAddress);
           --- SOme line of code---
            return Ok(List);
        }`